# insert text with R Code in markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I use the code below to insert text in rmarkdown.

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE} 
  cat("#", "We", "\n")
```
````

It worked well and gave me the output

```
# We
```

However, when I inserted some R code in this chunk like:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE} 
x <- 1:100
mean(x)
cat("#", "We", "\n") 
}
```
````

then it gave me the output:

```
# [1] 50.5 # We
```

In this case, `We` was no longer a header.

Comment: It gave you the same output using cat(mean(x))

Comment: OK, `cat` doesn't work.

Comment: Just put `cat('\n')` by itself between `mean(x)` and `cat('#', ... )`. I'm not wholly sure _why_ it works, but it works.

Comment: It works for me as well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

As opposed to `print`, `cat` doesn't start a new line. As `#` only indicates a section header when it is placed at the beginning of a line, an additional `\n` is required in front of `#`:

```
cat("\n# We\n")
```